# Web Scraping of Javascript table (with grid and list views) using Python - Beautiful Soup

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium

I'm trying to parse data from a json table from this website.

url - https://boxes.mysubscriptionaddiction.com/subscription_boxes_for/food.

I primarily need the name, ratings and descriptions of all the food subscription boxes listed. I'm facing a few challenges here. One is that there are 2 views to the table - grid and list view. How do we specify which table view we are referring to in our code? Second is that I am getting a

```
ValueError - Timeout value connect was Timeout(connect=<object object at 0x000002767CECD5C0>, 
read=<object object at 0x000002767CECD5C0>, total=None), but it must be an int, float or None.
```

Not sure what this means.
My code:

```
from pandas.io.html import read_html
from selenium import webdriver
import json
import requests
import os
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='C:\Drivers\geckodriver.exe')

driver.get('https://boxes.mysubscriptionaddiction.com/subscription_boxes_for/food')


table = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/span/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[3]/table')

table_html = table.get_attribute('innerHTML')

bs = BeautifulSoup(table_html, 'html.parser')

rows = bs.select('tbody tr')

print(bs)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to get the data you are looking for:  (`data` is a dict that contains the information)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

scrape_url = 'https://boxes.mysubscriptionaddiction.com/subscription_boxes_for/food'

r1 = requests.get(scrape_url)
page = r1.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
scripts = soup.find_all('script')

data_str = scripts[11].contents[0].strip()
data = json.loads(data_str,strict=False)
print(data['itemListElement'])
```

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful. The ratings are not coming through though. How should I modify the code to be able to download the ratings of subscription boxes as well? Could you please help!

Comment: I am not sure what is the 'rating'. Each item in the list contains a url (like 'https://boxes.mysubscriptionaddiction.com/box/taste-trunk-sweet'). Is this the rating? If it is - you need to read them entry by entry. If my answer helped you - feel free to vote up.

Comment: I mean bar that shows up below shipping details for every box. e.g. it is 124 ratings for the first box, Home Chef.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments/173400#173400